# Where timing between outputs matters, does the solution need to account for buffering?

Tags: discussion, code-golf, output

In certain languages (i.e. C), writes to streams like `stdout` can be buffered by default - what this means is that when one calls functions like `putchar()` or `printf()` to produce output, it is not necessarily written to the console immediately. Instead, it is (by default) printed when a linefeed is written, the buffer is filled, the stream is closed or the buffer is explicitly flushed (i.e. `fflush(stdout)`).

This becomes important in certain challenges, [like this one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/176319/simulate-a-cisco-ping), which require a delay between outputs and where the length of the source code matters.

Consider the two ways to achieve this:

- You flush the buffer after every write with a call, i.e. `fflush(stdout)`;
- or you turn off buffering for `stdout`, i.e. `setbuf(stdout,NULL)`

However, these do not come for free - especially in [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) the 14+ extra bytes can really hurt solutions. In fact, in the challenge linked above, none of the answers in C account for `stdout` being buffered.

Is it acceptable to assume that streams are non-buffering, even when by default they are not? Or, in other words, do solutions need to account for output potentially being buffered?

Comment: You're fine with assuming there's no buffering - you can see the correct amount of output when terminating early so I'd say it counts

Answer (score 2):

## It's ok iff the solution works in some configuration

For example you can specify "**<language> (output to terminal)**" in the header.

In my experience, even though languages have buffering by default they tend to only do line-buffer when the output is interactive, so if the code works fine when output to the terminal it's ok.

Comment: Unfortunately, C is the exact case where all output is buffered until a `<LF>` character is written or the buffer is explicitly flushed...